# How to fetch multiple subdirectories as one artifact with GoCD?

Tags: go-cd

I am using GoCD to build a project with a large number of modules and I have modeled it as a pipeline with two stages (stage 1 is to build the code, stage 2 is to run the tests). The directory structure after a successful build stage looks about like this:

```
myproject/
|-- myproject-module1
|   |-- build              <-- created by stage 1, required by stage 2
|   `-- src
|-- myproject-module2
|   |-- build              <-- created by stage 1, required by stage 2
|   `-- src
|-- myproject-module3
|   |-- build              <-- created by stage 1, required by stage 2
|   `-- src
`-- ... many more modules ...
```

In stage 1 I have configured a Build Artifact with source `*/build` and in stage 2 I'm trying to fetch all the build folders again with source `*` , with the intention that they would end up in the correct location next to the `src` folder inside each of the project modules.

Unfortunately, I have found no way to achieve this yet. GoCD seems to create a separate ZIP file of all the `*\build` folders and during the fetch, the file `*.zip` cannot be found (I assume that it really looks for a file with that exact name, instead of using wildcards). Of course I could hard-code all the module names and individually fetch `myproject-module[1:n]`, but that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Does anyone have some advice on how this could be achieved?

In [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/go-cd/kyzcUVXMRR8) from 2014, it is claimed that wildcards cannot be used to fetch artifacts. Is that really still the case?!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to do using built-in features of GoCD, but it should be definitely be possible using [REST API](https://api.gocd.org/current/).

Knowing current pipeline name, you can get all available stages of it and calculate previous one. Next, using a possibility to [download](https://api.gocd.org/current/#get-artifact-directory) an artifact directory as zip archive, you can get what you want.
So you can add this as a script for the second stage, which will get the zipped artifact and after that you can continue with testing.

To do that, I can recommend my implementation of GoCD API - [yagocd](https://github.com/grundic/yagocd). This python library would let you to program aforementioned logic in a natural way.
Some tips:

- you can get current pipeline name from *GO_PIPELINE_NAME* (there are a lot [environment variables](https://docs.gocd.org/15.3.0/faq/dev_use_current_revision_in_build.html) at your service)
- to find pipeline by name you can use *PipelineManager*: `go.pipelines.get($GO_PIPELINE_NAME, $GO_PIPELINE_COUNTER)`
- having pipeline instance, you can iterate stages by `pipeline_instance.stages` object
- having a stage, you can get it job and download directory by some path using `go.artifacts.directory_wait` method

If you would have questions about the implementation I can try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can select artifacts by wildcard, you just have to give the artifact a destination (attribute `dest` in the XML config). You can do that multiple times inside the same job, just use a different `dest` each time:

```xml
<artifact src="myproject/myproject-module1/build/*" dest="module1/" />
<artifact src="myproject/myproject-module2/build/*" dest="module2/" />
<artifact src="myproject/myproject-module3/build/*" dest="module3/" />
```

The corresponding `<fetchartifact ...>` tags then need to use `srcdir="module1"` etc.